# Why does Jackson think this object is a subtype (when it's really not)?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a relatively simple schema.  I have a `Subscription` object that holds a reference to a `User`.  On the flip side, I have a `User` object that has reference to an array of `Subscription`s.

The problem is that when Jackson tries to deserialize a `User` JSON payload that contains a `Subscription` array, it throws an `InvalidTypeIdException` claiming that `Subscription` couldn't be resolved as a subtype of `User`.  Why?  Because `Subscription` is NOT a subtype of `User`.

The `User` schema is as follows:

```
public class User extends Base {

  private List<Subscription> subscriptions;

  // other props & getters/setters
}
```

The `Subscription` schema is:

```
public class Subscription extends Base {

  private User user;

  // other props & getters/setters
}
```

Both classes have getters and setters defined.  For context, here is the `Base` class schema.  Note that we have it annotated with `@JsonTypeInfo`:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "model-type", visible = true)
public abstract class Base {
    protected String id;
}
```

The specific exception that is thrown is:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'Subscription' into a subtype of [simple type, class com.random.package.viewmodel.User]: known type ids = [User]
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@5c86366e; line: 17, column: 5] (through reference chain: com.random.package.viewmodel.User["subscriptions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

So why is this happening?  I know that `@JsonTypeInfo` is playing a part, but it is needed for other parts of our model schema.  Is it something to do with my `Base` class?

I was thinking this might be happening due to the bi-directionality between these two entities.  So I tried adding `@JsonManagedReference`, `@JsonBackReference`, and `@JsonIgnore` to the subscriptions field in User without any success.

So how can I make Jackson play nice with these two types?

For further reference here is the serialized JSON this is occurring on:

```
{
  "model-type": "User",
  "id": "peppermint-patty",
  "stub": false,
  "email": "random@randomemail.com",
  "username": "Peppermint Patty",
  "schema-version": "v1",
  "first-name": "Peppermint",
  "last-name": "Patty",
  "subscriptions": [
    {
      "id": "da73402f-9258-4284-a80a-5a050b4e721d",
      "schema-version": "v1",
      "model-type": "Subscription"    
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check your serialized json. Specifically `model-type` field.

Comment: I added an example serialized JSON payload that causes the issue

Comment: Have you tried the `@JsonSubTypes` annotation to list out the concrete subclasses available for Jackson to deserialize into?

Comment: How do you create `ObjectMapper`? Any specific features are enabled?

Comment: I could give `@JsonSubTypes` a shot ... I'd rather not do that though because then I'm going to have a massive list of subclasses (our schema is fairly large).  And for `ObjectMapper` we just have the default configuration provided by Spring Boot.

Comment: @heez unfortunately there is no way for deserializer to know what subtypes is available without `@JsonSubTypes`.